# Can we decide Red-blue cut problem in polynomial time?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory

Given a directed graph whose arcs are coloured red and blue and integers $r$ and $b$, can we decide in polynomial time whether the digraph has a cut with at most $r$ red arcs and at most $b$ blue arcs?

Related references can be found here http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/egres/open/Red-blue_cut_problem

It is known that the undirected version of the problem is in P even if there are weights on the edges.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi 　Thank you for your helpful answer!

Comment: Sorry for the quick comment (I was editing it), in the directed case the problem asks for a set $X$ with at most $r$ red incoming edges and at most $b$ blue incoming edges; it is also known as *directed unweighted global red-blue cut problem* (1DGRBC); see for example [this page](https://www.cs.elte.hu/egres/problems/prob_37/prob_37.html).

Comment: I think it would be nice to give some motivation/reason why you post a problem from another site here.